# camera-streamer breaks udev monitoring

Tags: linux, udev

I have a weird error with `camera-streamer` on Raspberry Pi with my custom-built Yocto image. When I stream ov5647 camera with `camera-streamer --camera-path=/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 --camera-type=libcamera --camera-format=YUYV --camera-width=1296 --camera-height=972 --http-port=8081`, it completely breaks udev monitoring. No events are captured by `udevadm monitor --udev`, no new devices are listed in `/dev`. Once I terminate streaming process, udev starts to work again (but actions performed during camera streaming, eg. USB inserts, are lost).

If I stream USB camera with `camera-streamer --camera-path=/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_C270_HD_WEBCAM_200901010001-video-index0 --camera-type=v4l2 --camera-format=MJPEG --camera-width=1280 --camera-height=720 --http-port=8081`, everything works fine. If I create a service with the same command, I use to stream ov5674 camera, udev monitor works fine. But when I make python script to monitor udev and switch cameras, udev monitor doesn't work inside this service and I won't get the actual filesystem state, when I run `ls /dev` inside the service.

It seems that the camera streamer breaks udev in some local context. I've been stuck on this for a few days and I'm not able to investigate, what's going on here. Do you have any ideas?